# Is the running time of this algorithm log n?

Tags: algorithm, performance, time-complexity, complexity-theory

I think this algorithm (or code) runs log n times because each time the amount of conditions to be evaluated decreases by a constant factor. Am I correct? If not, can you please explain to me what the running time is?

```
g(x) (* x > 1 is a real number *)

while x > 1 do
   x := x/3
```

Comment: yes, log n it is.

Comment: Yes. It is O(log n).

Comment: A photo-finish :-) It seems @Jean-FrançoisFabre arrived by 3 seconds faster.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

let this loop runs k times , which will be the time complexity of the algorithm,
At the end of :
1st iteration :x= (x/3<sup>1</sup>) 
2nd iteration :x= (x/3<sup>2</sup>)
3rd iteration :x= (x/3<sup>3</sup>)
.
.
.
.
kth iteration: x=(x/3<sup>k</sup>) <=1 (i.e. the terminating condtion)

Solving this: taking boundary conditions:
(x/3<sup>k</sup>) =1
therefor k=Log<sub>3</sub>x 
Hence the time complexity is O(LogN).
hope this helps.

Comment: awesome. It illustrate answer